# Target specific variable - command not found error - makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Referring [documentation](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/make-doc/make.html/Using-Variables.html#Target_002dspecific), wrote below target specific variable `LOGIN_COMMAND`.

Idea is to assign this variable only when user runs `make target1`

---

In the below `Makefile`:

```
target1 : LOGIN_COMMAND := $(shell aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')

target1:
    $(shell LOGIN_COMMAND)
    $(shell ls)
```

---

`make target1` is giving below error:

```
make: LOGIN_COMMAND: Command not found
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Just a guess, move that line under target `target1`, just before `$(LOGIN_COMMAND)`?

Comment: @dibery is that the valid syntax?

Comment: Not sure, so it's just a guess.

Comment: @dibery  I tried this... https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html.    Didn't work

Comment: The output (stdout) of `aws ecr ...` will be the command what do you want to run?

Comment: @uzsolt yes...I need to run the output of that command.. yes

Comment: @uzsolt the output of `aws ecr get-login ... | sed ...` is `docker login -u abc -p passw url`. This output I need to run

Comment: I rolled back your latest edits because the answer you already received no longer made any sense after those changes. Accept that answer (or post an answer of your own and accept that instead) and ask a new question if you still need help; probably link back here for background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850514/target-specific-variable-command-not-found-error-makefile?noredirect=1#comment105838685_59850514) one possible solution is the next:

```
target1:
      aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||' | sh
```

Note the trailing `sh`.

Another solution is creating a temporary file and run it:

```
AWSSH=output.sh
${AWSSH}:
    aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||' > $@
    chmod +x $@

target1: ${AWSSH}
    ./${AWSSH}
    rm -f ${AWSSH}
```

Comment: What is `$@`? With redirection operator

Comment: Why is it so complex to set target specific variables in makefile?

Comment: `$@` means the target (makefile-specific, read the documentation). The target-specific variables isn't goal of `make`.

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59883707/3317808

Answer (score 3):

I can't understand why everyone is always using `$(shell ...)` inside recipes.  Is there some kind of broken howto somewhere that recommends this?  It's so ubiquitous and I've never seen any example makefiles that do it (rightly so, because it's really not a good idea).

Anyway.  When you add `$(shell LOGIN_COMMAND)` what does that do?  It starts a shell and tells the shell to run the string `LOGIN_COMMAND`.  That's not a command the shell knows, so it gives you the error "command not found".  Try typing the string `LOGIN_COMMAND` at your shell prompt: it's the same thing.

Presumably you meant the contents of the variable `LOGIN_COMMAND`.  For that you need to write it as `$(LOGIN_COMMAND)` so make knows it's a variable reference not a string.

But using `$(shell ...)` in a recipe is redundant and confusing because a recipe IS a shell script already.

Plus it's not at all clear what you really want to do.  Are you trying to run the `ls` command on the local system?  Or are you trying to run it in on some remote system somewhere?

What do you want to do with the output of the `aws ecr get-login ... | sed ...` operation?

Before trying to write a makefile, be sure that you can perform the operations you want to do at your shell prompt.