# makefile - How to assign a value to a variable on specific target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the below code snippet:

```
IMAGES_TO_DELETE := $(aws ecr list-images --region $(ECR_REGION) --repository-name $(ECR_REPO) --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json)

.PHONY: target1 target2 cleanimage

cleanimage:
    ${DISPLAYINFO} "Clean untagged image from AWS ECR "
    aws ecr batch-delete-image --region $(ECR_REGION) --repository-name $(ECR_REPO) --image-ids "$(IMAGES_TO_DELETE)" || true
    ${DISPLAYINFO} "Done"

target1:
   # do something

target2:
   # do something
```

---

`IMAGES_TO_DELETE` gives imagelist, in JSON format.

`IMAGES_TO_DELETE` supposed to be assigned when `make cleanimage` executes

How to assign values to a variable under `cleanimage` target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a continuing misunderstanding about `make` variables.

It's not clear why this needs to be a variable at all. Just inline it into the target:

```
.PHONY: cleanimage

cleanimage:
    ${DISPLAYINFO} "Clean untagged image from AWS ECR "
    aws ecr batch-delete-image --region $(ECR_REGION) --repository-name $(ECR_REPO) \
        --image-ids "$$(aws ecr list-images --region $(ECR_REGION) --repository-name $(ECR_REPO) \
            --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json)" || true
    ${DISPLAYINFO} "Done"
```

As an aside `$(aws...)` is not a valid `make` function; you mean `$(shell aws ...)`; but again, there is no need to evaluate this in `make` at all if it is only needed in a single target.

Where you have repeated information, that's where it makes sense to refactor that into a variable so you only have to change it in one place.

```
ECRFLAGS := --region $(ECR_REGION) --repository-name $(ECR_REPO)

.PHONY: cleanimage

cleanimage:
    ${DISPLAYINFO} "Clean untagged image from AWS ECR "
    aws ecr batch-delete-image $(ECRFLAGS) \
        --image-ids "$$(aws ecr list-images $(ECRFLAGS) \
            --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json)" || true
    ${DISPLAYINFO} "Done"
```

Remember, a single dollar sign is evaluated by `make`. If you want to pass through a literal dollar sign to the shell, you need to double it.

Comment: Why `$$(aws...` ? `$(aws...` is used in bash

Comment: Because this is not Bash, this is Make. To pass through a literal dollar sign from `make` to the shell, you have to double it.

Comment: In bash we use `$?` to get the exit code of any command. In make, how to get the exit code of above AWS command?

Comment: We mostly don't (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) but you cad do something like `if json=$$(aws blah klah); then aws blab blab "$$json"; fi` If you set `SHELL=/bin/bash` you can use `PIPESTATUS` and other Bash extensions but this obviously wrecks the portability of your `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

Make variables must *always* be surrounded with parens or braces.  If not, then only the next character is part of the variable.

So when you write `$ECR_REGION`, make will expand the variable `$E` (which is probably empty) then append the string `CR_REGION`.  Not what you want.

You must write `$(ECR_REGION)` (or `${ECR_REGION}` if you prefer: they're equivalent to make).

Ditto for `$(ECR_REPO)` and `$(IMAGES_TO_DELETE)`.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html